# Dual partition a large drive for use by Mac and Windows

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, hfs+

I have a 3TB USB3 drive that I want to use between my Mac and Windows laptops.  A 1.5TB partition will be used for Time Machine and another 1.5TB partition will be used by Windows for file storage.  The Windows partition will be ex-FAT because I want the files to be read/write able from both machines.  The drive will be swapped between the two machines periodically.

On what OS should I create the two partitions so that it's usable by both OSes?  I started by creating partitions in Windows.  The Mac can see the Windows partition but when I try to format the parition for Time Machine, Disk Utility says:

**Volume Erase failed with the error: MediaKit reports not enough space on device for requested operation.**

Help.

Comment: I would strongly suggest partitioning the drive from your Mac. Most likely the partition you created in Windows is not in a format that Mac is expecting.

Comment: Learned that the hard way.  I repartitioned on the Mac and now it works as expected on Mac and Windows.